# Add a day to datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hi friends and sorry about this noob question but i don't get support from the theme developers.
I have a datepicker on one of my websites and would like to add a day to the current date.

So i found a js file what is including some code like this. I am sure you have a solution for this, but i don't ;-)

The goal is that people are not able to book or make a reservation for the same day.

```js
$( '#reservations-date-selector' ).datepicker().datepicker( 'option', 'dateFormat', dateFormat ).datepicker( 'setDate', new Date() );
```

Comment: Something like that? https://irishdotnet.dev/post/How-to-add-one-day-to-the-calendar-date-selected-using-jquery-ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$( '#reservations-date-selector' ).datepicker().datepicker( 'option', 'dateFormat', dateFormat ).datepicker( 'setStartDate', new Date(new Date().getTime()+(1*24*60*60*1000)) );
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just had to change "setStartDate" to "setDate", then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the `minDate` option to 1 for one day after today

```js
$(function() {
  let dateFormat = "d MM, y";
  $('#reservations-date-selector')
    .datepicker({
      minDate: 1,
      dateFormat: dateFormat
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" integrity="sha256-p6xU9YulB7E2Ic62/PX+h59ayb3PBJ0WFTEQxq0EjHw=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="text" id="reservations-date-selector" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much, anyway i used the answer below, cause i have seen it before and also worked ;-)